# how does one check their connection in chessbase.com

Tags: chessbase

I get lots of messages that say to check my connection or I will lose on time.  AFAIK I am always connected and see no obvious way to 'check my connection'

Today I was up a piece against a much stronger player when that message showed up.  I tried to see of other aps were connected to the internet by checking my email and I was connected.  In less than a minute when I had returned I had apparently lost on time even though my connection was clearly active then on chessbase.

The other guy had timed it to call the arbiter and get a win declared.   Makes me think he knows how to make my connection appear to be gone because many times I click arbiter over and over and get no response at all although sometimes it is they are connected or they are gone and I do get the win.

Chessbase appears to be full of bugs as that message usually appears after I see that it had switched servers.  Why it needs to switch servers is a big mystery too,  but my question is:
HOW DO YOU CHECK A CONNECTION?  When I reload the page I have a connection but that always loses the position I was in and starts me over with a new game.  There must be another way to check a connection.  And how do you reconnect should you find out you are not connected.  This seems to be a chessbase problem not on my PC end.

Answer (score 1):

"Check your connection" means that the application is having problems connecting to the internet, so it asks you to "check your internet connection".

Suppose your computer was connected to the router with a cable:

[image: computer cable]

This cable is faulty, and if it gets moved, you shortly lose the connection. You would need to either avoid it being touched or -longterm- replacing the faulty wire.

If you are on wireless, the same could happen, you might be losing packets although that's less visual. That could be due to other people using the wireless spectrum or even their microwave.

As a way to test your connectivity, you can open a command line prompt, and execute a command like `ping 8.8.8.8` to ping a known server (in this example Google DNS) and see if some packets get lost. If they are, you should then take steps to correct it, but that's outside the scope of this Stack Exchange. You might want to ask your ISP / computer technician fix it.